# Cannot navigate back in Template10

Tags: c#, xaml, navigation, template10

I'm trying to navigate back to my MainPage from this secondary page. I tried to use `NavigationService.GoBack()` but I got `NullReferenceException`.

I didn't change anything from the viewmodel. What I intended to do is to save user input into SQLite first, then navigate back to MainPage

Here is my code from `DetailPage.xaml.cs`

```
    private SQLiteService database = new SQLiteService();
    DetailPageViewModel vm = new DetailPageViewModel();

    public DetailPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Disabled;
    }

    private void yesButton_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        var _name = Name.Text;
        var _uptake = UptakeTime.SelectedIndex + 1; // database index Morning start at 1
        var _intake = int.Parse(Intake.Text);

        vm.ProcessData(_name, _intake, _uptake);
    }
```

Here is the `DetailPageViewModel.cs`

```
    SQLiteService database = new SQLiteService();

    public DetailPageViewModel()
    {
        if (Windows.ApplicationModel.DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled)
        {
            Value = "Designtime value";
        }
    }

    private string _Value = "Default";
    public string Value { get { return _Value; } set { Set(ref _Value, value); } }

    public override async Task OnNavigatedToAsync(object parameter, NavigationMode mode, IDictionary<string, object> state)
    {
        Value = (state.ContainsKey(nameof(Value))) ? state[nameof(Value)]?.ToString() : parameter?.ToString();
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public override async Task OnNavigatedFromAsync(IDictionary<string, object> pageState, bool suspending)
    {
        if (suspending)
        {
            pageState[nameof(Value)] = Value;
        }
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public override async Task OnNavigatingFromAsync(NavigatingEventArgs args)
    {
        args.Cancel = false;
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void GotoMainPage() =>
        NavigationService.GoBack();    

    public void ProcessData(string _name, int _type, int _uptake)
    {
        database.AddNewItem(_name, _uptake, _type);
        GotoMainPage();
    }
```

Side note : I tried to access the `GotoMainPage` from `Detail.xaml.cs` by using `vm.GotoMainPage()`, but it still returned exception

Comment: Which line of code threw the null reference exception? Is the Navigation Service null?

Comment: this.Frame.Navigage(typeof(Mainpage));

Comment: @GlenThomas I got the exception from `NavigationService.GoBack()`

Comment: @MatthiasHerrmann it's actually worked, thanks.

Comment: @MatthiasHerrmann mind if you make that into answer? So I will vote on that

Answer (score 0):

- To navigate between different Pages use the `Frame.Navigate` method.
- An example for page Navigation to a xaml Page called Mainpage is: 
  `this.Frame.Navigage(typeof(Mainpage));`

For further Information look at the Documentation: [Frame.Navigate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.frame.navigate(v=vs.110).aspx)

The Namespace being used is called `System.Windows.Controls`.